# Changing image in a list item in a list view dynamically

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

In my project I have a list view consisting of list items each containing an image. Now when a particular list item is clicked, new activity with respect to that item is opened and it has 3 buttons. Depending on which button is clicked the image in that particular list item is changed.
Each list item is associated with specific row from the database, I wanted to know how do I recognize the particular button click and change image view directly in the list item.

My custom Adapter's getView() Method is as follows

```
    public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    private EventDBAdapter dbHelper;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public SpecialAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to, int i) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private int[] colors = new int[] { 0xAAFFFFF, 0xAAc0c0c0 };

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      int colorPos = position % colors.length;
      view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
      return view;
}

    }
```

Each list item is inflated from this view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 >

<View
android:layout_width="1dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvListTitle"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:background="#CC3232"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvListTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#108070"
    android:text="Title in list"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvListTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00:00 to 00:00"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvListTitle"
    android:textColor="#138F6A"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvListWhere"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvListTime"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Crystal plaza , Andheri (West) . "
    android:textColor="#138F6A"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvListDetails"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvListWhere"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="This is gonna contain brief summary about the event"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvListDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="14th January"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvListDay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvListDetails"
    android:text="Monday"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivStatus"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvListWhere"
    android:src="@drawable/yes" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How are you setting data to `ListView`, are you using `CursorAdapter` or you have made your own adapter? what kind of database, does it reside on the server or a local sqlite database?

Comment: @AdilSoomro I have made my own adapter and data resides on local sqlite database.

Comment: post some code for ListView and Adapter's getView(), how is your data model?

Comment: @AdilSoomro The src of image view in above xml is to be changed on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved , i am using the url of image on SD card and storing it in the sqlite db and populating list view with contents of database row wise

Answer (score 1):

You can use startactivityforresult()

OR

Use three static variables in your current activity and set them according to the button pressed in your new activity opened and when comes to the previous activity check the variables and set the image accordingly.

Comment: If i use your second option , how do i find for which list item the button was clicked in the next activity (non list view activity) and change only that particular list item?

Comment: i advise you to use first one but if you use second then again you need to use one extra variable which you should update when clicking on any list item with its position..

Comment: No my problem isnt resolved , how would startActivityforresult() help here , its not necessary i want to switch to my list activity on button click